# ++i operator difference in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, int, increment, language-specifications

I have the following code written in both C++ and C#

```
 int i=0;
 ++i = 11;
```

After this C# compiler brings an error

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
```

But C++ compiler generate this code with no error and I got a result `11` for value of `i`. What's the reason of this difference?

Comment: offtopic: why do you want to increment it and then directly set it to 11? The increment makes no sense.

Comment: What is the use for this code?

Comment: `someArray[++i] = 11` would make more sense.

Comment: It's just interesting to me. @mesiesta explained correctly why is it so.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The difference is that pre-increment operator is **lvalue** in C++, and isn't in C#.
In C++ `++i` returns a reference to the incremented variable. In C# `++i` returns the incremented value of variable i.
So in this case `++i` is **lvalue** in C++ and **rvalue** in C#.

From C++ specification about prefix increment operator

> The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a
>   completely-defined object type. The value is the new value of the
>   operand; it is an **lvalue**.

**P.S.** postfix increment operator i++ isn't lvalue in both C# and C++, so this lines of code will bring error in both languages.

```
 int i=0;
 i++ = 11;
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that `++i = 11` invokes undefined in C++03 because you are modifying `i` twice without an intervening sequence point. It is well defined in C++11, however: first the increment, then the assignment.

Answer (score 5):

C# and C++ are 2 totally different languages and concepts. They only share the name because their syntax is based on C. So actually "why this works on C# but not on C++" makes no sense as a question. It's the same as saying why a table is called "table" in English, but "mesa" in Spanish. Because it was decided to be that way.

C# simply does not allow such syntax.

In C++ you're allowed to: first `++i` is computed, which makes `i = 1`, and then 11 is assigned to `i`, which makes `i = 11`.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. The question *is* common to the C language and many things that work in C++ also work in C#! It's a perfectly valid question IMO, particularly since in C++ the code in question represents a statement that makes no logical sense.

Comment: Harsh? Why harsh? I'm just stating that C# and C++ have nothing in common except being based on C. The question is not common to C, because he's not asking about C, and in C that sentence works perfectly, and it does not in C#, which just demonstrates C# has nothing to do with C except the name and the syntax (which btw is copied by a lot of language like Perl, Java and such).

Comment: C# and C++ have similarities... There aren't different like for example Java and Haskell. So for me it's a valid question and it's interesting for me to know.

Comment: They're different like Java and Haskell, but I'm not going to state all the differences and the very few similarities. It's indeed interesting to know, but I personally wouldn't have formulated the question that way.

Answer (score 2):

the semantics are very different. In c++ the semantics are that you assign the value 11 to the storage location identified by i. In C# the semantics are equal to the semantics of the below statement

```
1=11
```

That is it's equal to trying to assign the value 11 to the value 1 which the C# compiler does not allow. (Fortran compilers actually do allow this and that can create hellish debugging scenarios)